# Full Join 2 lists with 3 key values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'd like to fully join 2 tables on 3 key values, there doesn't need to be 0 value on blank cells if it makes it easier to understand (Some Array Formulas can be really confusing)

**I have income:**

[image]

**I have expense:**

[image]

**I'd like to fully join the 2 tables so it results like this:**

[image]

How can I achieve this in Google Sheets?

Here's the example sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O1rZUstDNSXPdUVXvaDfPO4rAQs2cJWHimfGxbddtNU/edit#gid=490516150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Income!A2:C; Expense!A2:C})), "where Col1 is not null"),
 {IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Income!A2:C; Expense!A2:C})),
 "where Col1 is not null")),,999^99)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Income!A2:C),,999^99)), Income!D2:D}, 2, 0), 0),
  IFERROR(VLOOKUP(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SORT(UNIQUE({Income!A2:C; Expense!A2:C})),
 "where Col1 is not null")),,999^99)), 
 {TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(Expense!A2:C),,999^99)), Expense!D2:D}, 2, 0), 0)}})
```

[image: 0]